# React-select not showing icon on items

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Hi i am working one project ,in this project i neeed to create `dropdown menu` with `icon` .The frontend is created using `Reactjs` .Now for the `Dropdown` i am using `React-select` . Its showing the dropdown , My question is how can show an `icon` with each item .

//DropDownn.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import CheckSquare from "./CheckSquare";
import FontAwesome from "react-fontawesome";
import Clock from "./Clock";
const customSingleValue = ({ data }) => (
  <div className="input-select">
    <div className="input-select__single-value">
      {data.icon && <span className="input-select__icon">{data.icon}</span>}
      <span>{data.label}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const UserInfo = () => {
  const statusOptions = [
    { value: "available", label: "Available", icon: <CheckSquare /> },
    { value: "dnd", label: "Busy", icon: <Clock /> },
    { value: "away", label: "Away", icon: <Clock /> },
    { value: "Right back away", label: "back", icon: <CheckSquare /> }
  ];
  const [presence, setPresence] = useState();
  const changeSelectHandler = (pres) => {
    setPresence(pres);
    console.log(pres);
  };
  const renderPresenceOption = (option) => {
    return (
      <div className="presenceOption">
        <FontAwesome name="circle" className={"presenceIcon " + option.value} />
        {option.value}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderPresenceValue = (presence) => {
    return (
      <div className="currentPresence">
        <FontAwesome
          name="circle"
          className={"presenceIcon " + presence.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Select
      value={presence}
      defaultValue={statusOptions[0]}
      options={statusOptions}
      clearable={false}
      onChange={changeSelectHandler}
      components={{ SingleValue: customSingleValue }}
      optionRenderer={renderPresenceOption}
      valueRenderer={renderPresenceValue}
    />
  );
};

export default UserInfo;
```

[image: I want Exactly like this]

SandBox link :[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-using-debounce-react-forked-htvqc?file=/src/CustomSelect.js)

```
   i want like like the above image
```

[sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-using-debounce-react-forked-htvqc?file=/src/CustomSelect.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the react-select style-config

```
import Select, { StylesConfig } from 'react-select';
```

and then add the styleConfig to your select box, something like this, when your options should have an icon prop with the icon img url -

```
const iconStyles: StylesConfig = {
  option: ({ data }) => {
    return {
      ':before': {
        backgroundImage: `url(${data.icon})`,
        content: '" "',
        display: 'block',
        marginRight: 8,
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
      },   
    };
  },
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={myOptions[0]}
    options={myOptions}
    styles={iconStyles}
  />
);
```

you can view a similar example from react-select here -
https://codesandbox.io/s/pnhzt?module=/example.tsx

Comment: Guy Perry: Still not showing icon https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-using-debounce-react-forked-htvqc?file=/src/CustomSelect.js

Comment: you have a couple of errors:
1. icon prop needs to be a url string.
2. line 22 in your codesandbox link 'option' instead of 'statusOptions', since you are setting the style for the select option

Comment: By the way, I checked out the demo in the react-select site, and they used text emojis as icons - {
    "value": "/props",
    "icon": "❤️",
    "label": "Simpler and more extensible"
}

Comment: Can you please create an example

Comment: sure - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-0m5bj?file=/example.tsx

Comment: Is it possible to use Svg icons here

Comment: sure, your backgroundImage can be an svg icon, also the example I've sent you was in typescript, I made a small modification and saved it as javascript, so it won't be confusing - https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-0m5bj?file=/example.js

Comment: Guy Perry : Sorry but i am not able to set Svg icon . Can you Please Update this Example. I will be very thanful to you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-using-debounce-react-forked-htvqc?file=/src/CustomSelect.js